# Java SQLite table locked

Tags: java, sqlite, locked

In my application (being developed with Netbeans/Windows) I open my database in the main GUI, then call several functions each of which loads specified tables into in-memory data structures. The connection is passed as an argument to each function. I am closing all Statements, ResultsSets along the way. All of this works very well. Then in run a an .exe (created with C++) in a process using ProcessBuilder. The exe generates a text file.  After the exe completes I need to delete an existing database table and  read the text file into it.

Now, here's the problem. There is a locked table error when I attempt to delete the table. Note that the exe does nothing with the database or any other database.

So, the question is why this happens. BTW, The work-around I've used is to close the connection before running the exe process, then reestablish the connection afterwards. This is awkward at best.

Comment: Do you have any transactions open? Does removing the call to the C++ process affect anything? Hard to help without seeing any code.

Answer (score -1):

Only one process should be accessing a SQLite database at a time. You should not try to read the database from a C++ executable and Java at the same time.

Two solutions are possible:

1. Try eliminating the C++ executable
2. Disconnect your Java GUI before running the exe process and then reconnect afterwards.

In my opinion, the first option is the correct one...

Comment: Thanks. However, as I said, the C++ .exe does absolutely nothing with any database.  One day I will rewrite the C++ in Java, but for now need to keep it in C++... it's someone else's code and don't want to be reconverting it every time he makes a change. If I understand you correctly, your second option is what I'm now doing as a work-around. So the mystery persists.

Comment: -1: SQLite handles concurrent access just fine; accessing the database from multiple connections won't corrupt it (unless you intentionally disable locking). The worst you'll get is an occasional busy error, but in that case you can just wait for a bit then try again.